# swagger node multiple security handlers with logic AND

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a swagger node express app and I am not sure how to have two security handlers?

I have two SecurityDefinitions in my swagger.yaml

```
securityDefinitions:
  appKeyA:
    type: apiKey
    name: Authorization
    in: header
  appKeyB:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-APP-ID
```

in my route

```
/foo
security:
        - appKeyA: []
          appKeyB: []
```

So logical AND

In my app.js

```
app.use(
    middleware.swaggerSecurity({
      //manage token function in the 'auth' module
      appKeyA: auth.verifyToken

    })
  );
```

It successfully runs the code in my verifyToken function

```
exports.verifyToken = function(req, authOrSecDef, token, callback) {
   ...
}
```

Now where do I put the second function to prevent getting
Error: unknown security handler: appKeyB

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when I tried to figure out how to simply get the security middleware working.

Firstly, the security middleware **MUST** be added to the middleware chain before the swaggerRouter.

Secondly, for your question you simply add it to the security definition like this:

```js
app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());
app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

// This must be placed before the swaggerRouter
app.use(
  middleware.swaggerSecurity({
    //manage token function in the 'auth' module
    appKeyA: auth.verifyToken,
    appKeyB: auth.verifyToken2 //Add the second token to verify appKeyB
  })
);
app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(options));
app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());
```

Furthermore here I introduced a new verification method called verifyToken2, add this function to your auth file so it exports two functions :)

```js
exports.verifyToken2 = function(req, authOrSecDef, token, callback) {
  ...
}
```